# Resizing website using Ctrl++ or Ctrl+-

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

Is there a method of detecting whther website has been resized?

I'm using jscrollpane and it works fine, but when I resize it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> the bottom part get's "eaten" unless I refresh the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `.resize()` work?

http://api.jquery.com/resize/